# Send local notifications in Android O

Tags: android, android-notifications, background-process, scheduler, android-8.0-oreo

I cannot believe I'm asking this, but I want to schedule notifications in my Android app (repeating or not).

I managed to do this easily following the Android training article, using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and `Service`s. But now, since I have to target the last Android APIs for my future updates, I have to make some changes to my code.

I believe that `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` has been **deprecated**, so I'm using a simple `BroadcastReceiver` instead.

**Current implementation**

Whenever I want to schedule an alarm, I'm sending an `Intent` to my `BroadcastReceiver`, and in the `onReceive` method, instead of the old call to `startWakefulService(context, service);`, I did a `context.startService(service);`. But with the **background limitations**, I cannot start a service when my app is in the background...

I have an error: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service: app is in background**

**How can I change my code effectively to handle this problem?** The service I call is the one that sends the notifications to the user.

**Code**

1. Set the alarm

   ```
   Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
   // put the extras for the notification details
   // ...
   alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idNotif, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
           millis, interval, alarmIntent);
   ```
2. The `Intent` is received in the `AlarmReceiver` class

   ```
   // onReceive method
   context.startService(service); // The ERROR is raised here when my app is in bg
   ```

**EDIT**

I cannot use `JobScheduler` as it will not guarantee me that the notifications will be sent in time.

I cannot start a foreground service too to send my notifications.

Comment: you can use `Foreground service`, `JobIntentService` or `JobService`

Comment: Yes, @egoldx is right. You can use any of the mentioned options. I would suggest to go ahead with `JobScheduler` as it seems like the most recommended option for tasks like these. Check the link for more info. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler

Comment: `JobScheduler` cannot guarantee that the notifications will be sent in time, which critical for me

Comment: You can use Work Manager introduced in android jetpack, read [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) for more.

Comment: Work Manager is not suited for sending notifications

Comment: @egoldx can you explain to me how I can transform my code to use a foreground service?

Comment: Well, everything is the same, but you have to call `ContextCompact.startForegroundService()` instead of regular `startService` and then in your service you have to call `Service.startForeground()` immediately (foregournd service needs to be showing notification while running). If you dont call startForeground with some notification, you will get exception.

Comment: @Youb did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an useful article, you can find out more by visiting this [website](http://www.singhajit.com/schedule-local-notification-in-android/)

To simplify:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
    }
```

The above code will schedule an alarm after 30 seconds and it will broadcast the `notificationIntent`.

Comment: So, the answer is just to send notification in the `onReceive` method?

Comment: I've tried your solution but it does not work reliably: sometimes the notifications are not sent because the broadcast receiver is killed and doesn't finish it's job...